# I am 5-minute late?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

Which of the options are acceptable and which are not? Any other suggestions/corrections?

1. I'm 5 minutes late
2. I'm 5-minute late
3. I'm running 5 minutes late
4. I'm sorry for being five minutes late.
5. I'm sorry for being late by five minutes.
6. I'm late by 5 minutes
7. I'm late in 5 minutes

Comment: Numbers 2 and 7 are not grammatical. All the others are possible, and which you use depends on the context and purpose of the remark you are making.

Comment: 2. and 7. don't make sense. 4. and 5. are obviously apologies rather than statements. 'I'm running five minutes late' means that you have not yet arrived at your destination but are five minutes behind where you would need to be to make it on time.

Comment: **Context*: **a.** heads-up that I'm going to be late (_I'm 5 minutes late_). **b.** Apologized for being late. Any better sentences than those above?

Comment: There are literally a thousand. What are you trying to achieve with this question. What are you trying to say.

Comment: It's ok, I've got the required information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further context, expressions 1 and 3 seem OK to me. The others, or at least some of them, might arise in certain situations, but in general I'd stick with 1 and 3.